# how to do bitwise operation on escape sequence characters in python

Tags: python, escaping, bit-manipulation, sequence

```
>>>data='\x3a'
>>>st=data.encode.('hex')
>>>st
'3a'
>>>int(st) & 1
Tracback (most recent call last):
     File "(stdin)",line 1 in <module>
ValueError:invalit literal for int() with base 10: '3a'
```

I would like to perform some bitwise operation on the data (which i receive from my i2c slave device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't encode to hex at all; just use `data` *directly* and use the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) to turn the bytevalue into an integer; you don't want the hex representation here

```
ord(data) & 1
```

If you did cast to hex, you'd have to interpret the value as a hexadecimal integer:

```
int(st, 16) & 1
```

but with the encoding to hex that's more work than is required.

Demo:

```
>>> data = '\x3a'
>>> ord(data)
58
>>> ord(data) & 1
0
>>> int(data.encode('hex'), 16)
58
>>> int(data.encode('hex'), 16) & 1
0
```